# How does IEnumerable<T> work in background

Tags: c#, linq, oop, interface, ienumerable

I am wandering about the more in-depth functionality of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Basically, it works as an intermediary step in execution. For example, if you write:

```
IEnumerable<int> temp = new int[]{1,2,3}.Select(x => 2*x);
```

The result of the `Select` function will not be calculated (enumerated) until something is done with temp to allow it (such as `List<int> list = temp.ToList()`).

However, what puzzles me is, since `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface, it cannot, by definition, be instantiated. So, what is the collection the actual items (in the example `2*x` items) reside in?

Moreover, if we were to write `IEnumerable<int> temp = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10);`, what would be the underlying collection where the 1s are stored (array, list, something else)?

I cannot seem to find a thorough (more in-depth) explanation as to the actual implementation of this interface and its functionality (for example, if there is an underlying collection, how does the `yield` keyword work).

Basically, what I am asking for is a more elaborate explanation on the functionality of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Some hidden framework class that exposes the IEnumerable interface. Does it really matter?

Comment: the underlying code/object returned implements  IEnumerable<int>

Comment: _what would be the underlying collection where the 1s are stored (array, list, something else)?_ they are not stored in anywhere. that's the point of lazy loading

Comment: @YoryeNathan, I want to know, for the sake of knowing. I've been using it for years, but never really went in-depth. I assumed it was some runtime-construction thing, I just didn't know the details of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all objects that implement `IEnumerable` defer execution in some way.  The API of the interface makes it *possible* to defer execution, but it doesn't *require* it.  There are likewise implementations that *don't* defer execution in any way.

> So, what is the collection the actual items (in the example 2*x items) reside in?

There is none.  Whenever the next value is requested it computes that one value *on demand*, gives it to the caller, and then forgets the value.  It doesn't store it anywhere else.

> Moreover, if we were to write `IEnumerable<int> temp = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10);`, what would be the underlying collection where the 1s are stored (array, list, something else)?

There wouldn't be one.  It would compute each new value *immediately when you ask for the next value* and it won't remember it afterward.  It only stores enough information to be able to compute the next value, which means it only needs to store the element and the number of values left to yield.

While the actual .NET implementations will use much more concise means of creating such a type, creating an enumerable that defers execution is not particularly hard.  Doing so even the long way is more tedious than difficult.  You simply compute the next value in the `MoveNext` method of the iterator.  In the example you asked of, `Repeat`, this is easy as you only need to compute *if* there is another value, not what it is:

```
public class Repeater<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private int count;
    private T element;

    public Repeater(T element, int count)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.count = count;
    }
    public T Current { get { return element; } }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            count--;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

(I've omitted an `IEnumerable` type that just returns a new instance of this type, or a static `Repeat` method that creates a new instance of that enumerable.  There isn't anything particularly interesting to see there.)

A slightly more interesting example would be something like `Count`:

```
public class Counter : IEnumerator<int>
{
    private int remaining;

    public Counter(int start, int count)
    {
        Current = start;
        this.remaining = count;
    }
    public int Current { get; private set; }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (remaining > 0)
        {
            remaining--;
            Current++;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Here we're not only computing if we have another value, but what that next value is, each time a new value is requested of us.

Answer (score 5):

Implementation shouldn't matter. All these (LINQ) methods return `IEnumerable<T>`, interface members are the only members you can access, and that should be enough to use them.

However, if you really have to know, you can find actual implementations on http://sourceof.net.

- [Enumerable.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

But, for some of the methods you won't be able to find explicit class declaration, because some of them use `yield return`, which means proper class (with state machine) is generated by compiler during compilation. e.g. `Enumerable.Repeat` is implemented that way:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
    long max = ((long)start) + count - 1;
    if (count < 0 || max > Int32.MaxValue)
        throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("count");
    return RangeIterator(start, count); 
}

static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        yield return start + i;
}
```

You can read more about that on MSDN: [Iterators (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx)

Comment: Why the vote down? That is the one true valid answer to this question. It is an interface, and the framework hides the implementation, so what? Should be given +2 just for linking the source code of the implementation.

Comment: Why is this upvoted?  It answers none of the question in the OP.  It doesn't explain the concepts that he has stated he doesn't understand.  All it says is that he shouldn't care about them (to which I disagree, btw) and links to some content that he already stated he doesn't understand the semantics of.  This really only answers a few of the the questions for someone that already understands the semantics of the behavior that the OP explicitly stated he didn't understand the semantics of.

Answer (score 2):

> So, what is the collection the actual items (in the example 2*x items) reside in?

It is not residing anywhere. There is code that will produce the individual items "on demand" when you iterate, but the `2*x` numbers are not computed upfront. They are also not stored anywhere, unless you call `ToList` or `ToArray`.

> Moreover, if we were to write IEnumerable temp = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10);, what would be the underlying collection where the 1s are stored (array, list, something else)?

The same picture is here: the returned implementation of `IEnumerable` is not public, and it returns its items on demand, without storing them anywhere.

C# compiler provides a convenient way to implement `IEnumerable` without defining a class for it. All you need is to declare your method return type as `IEnumerable<T>`, and use `yield return` to supply values on as-needed basis.