# How does c# decide which implementation to use for IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

I just started learning C# and I'm a bit confused with the following piece of code from MSDN:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings =
            Enumerable.Repeat("I like programming.", 15);
```

Since IEnumerable is an interface and Enumerable.Repeat<>() returns IEnumerable type, how is "strings" implemented? As a List or something other container?

Comment: Just browse the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e2850cfe2b0cc87f

Comment: The inner workings of any enumerable are deliberately hidden from the end user. Typically there is going to be some internal collection (like a list) but you are not supposed to know for sure. In this case a loop with `yield` statements suffice, and use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no internal collection in this case. In fact some enumerables may be infinite so you cannot always expect internal collection. In this particular method there is a field that holds the value and a loop that counts how many times move next is called. If it gets to the specified count it stops the iteration. Of course this is implemented using the iterators feature of C# which makes implementing it trivial.

Answer (score 0):

That is an implementation detail. The signature of [`Enumerable<string>.Repeat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348899%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) promises the result being of `IEnumerable<string>`, and that's what it returns.

Whether this value is returned as an array, List or generated in any other way (the latter being the case) that implements the required `IEnumerable<T>`, doesn't matter. See the Remarks section on MSDN though, saying:

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

If you're interested in the actual implementation, see [the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627798/how-does-ienumerablet-work-in-background).

Answer (score 0):

Currently anyway, the type returned is:

```
Enumerable/'<RepeatIterator>d__b5`1'<string>.
```

You can't define a variable as that tpye because it's an anonymous type. Anonymous types are implemented by compiling a type with a name that while valid .NET is not valid C# so you can't possibly accidentally create another type with the same name.

This particular anonymous type is the sort used to implement `yield`. Again, when you code `yield` in C# this is compiled by creating .NET classes that implement `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.

Your code doesn't care about any of this, it just care that it gets something implementing the interface.

For that point consider the validity of:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SomeStrings()
{
  if(new Random().Next(0, 2) == 0)
    return new HashSet<string>{"a", "b", "c"};
  else
    return new List<string>{"a", "b", "c"};
}
```

Calling code won't know if it got a `HashSet<string>` or a `List<string>` and won't care. It won't care if version 2.0 actually returns `string[]` or uses `yield`.

You could create your own `Repeat` as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(T element, int count)
{
  while(count-- > 0)
    yield return element;
}
```

We have a complication though in that we want to thrown an exception if `count` is less than zero. We can't just do:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(T element, int count)
{
  if(count < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
  while(count-- != 0)
    yield return element;
}
```

This doesn't work because the throw won't happen until we actually enumerate it (if we ever do) as `yield`-defined enumerations don't run any code until the first enumeration. Therefore we need;

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(T element, int count)
{
  if(count < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
  return RepeatImpl<T>(element, count);
}
private static IEnumerable<T> RepeatImpl<T>(T element, int count)
{
  while(count-- != 0)
    yield return element;
}
```